# Netty websocket server doesn't pass control to handler

Tags: java, netty

I created websocket server using Netty 4.1.0.beta3 It is based on the example from Netty repository, but I use shared executor (scheduled single thread executor):

```
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1, executor);
    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
    b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
            .childHandler(new WsServerInitializer(this));
    b.bind(port);
```

Also `WsServerInitializer` is similar to that from netty repo:

```
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
        pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
        pipeline.addLast(serverHandler);
    }
```

The main problem is that the sever often (not always) remains in connecting state. I checked that control goes to `LoggingHandler.channelRead()` and then my `serverHandler` is added to pipeline in `ServerBootstrap.channelRead()`. But after that any of `channelRegisterd()`, `channelActive()`, `channelRead()` in `serverHandler` are not called. Both netty threads are running and `NioEventLoop.run()` is processing some tasks. Problem disappears when worker loop group receives its own thread. My question is: how can I debug it? I just don't know where to start. Any suggestions?

Comment: What you mean with receive it's own Thread ?

Comment: I just do `EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1)`.

Comment: Are you sure you have enough threads in your Executor to be able to handle 2 * cores ?

Comment: You were right. I need more threads. Thanks!